# A variable may not have been initialized, using 2 classes

Tags: java, class, initialization

I'm new to Stackoverflow (as well as coding) and I'm really hoping you could help me out here. I'm making a text-based butterfly effect game on BlueJ. I have my main "RPG" code first, then my "Level1ZombieClass" after it. My problem is that I keep getting an initialization error for my userclass variable (Because I need to have it in my zombie class in order for the "if" statements/combat work, and I have no idea how to fix it. In the first set of code I wanted to add my zombie class so I don't have a huge chunk of code that can be easily replaced by a couple lines. Again, the problem being the userclass variable is something that the user defines, not something that I define in the code.[Just a screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9UJL.png). Thank you so much guys, really appreciate your help.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RPG
{
public static void main (String [] args)
{
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String name;
   int playerClass;
   int wincount=0;
   int userhealth=100+(wincount)*3;
   int comphealth=100;
   int hc;
   int userChoice=1;
   int killcount;
   int regularAttackD;
   int regularAttackHC;
   int powerAttackD;
   int powerAttackHC;
   int shield;
   int quickAttackHC;
   int quickAttackD;
   int compChoice=1;
   int playerchoice;

   Random a = new Random ();
   Random b = new Random ();
   Random c = new Random ();
   Random d = new Random ();
   Random e = new Random ();
   Random f = new Random ();
   Random g = new Random ();
   Random h = new Random (); 

   System.out.println ("Welcome to the zombie apocalypse...\nIn this text-driven game you will need to make decisions based on game prompts.\nYour decisions will determine your own fate."); 
   System.out.println ("What would you like to be called?");
   name = in.next();
   System.out.println (name + ",in this game you may need to fight enemies in a turn-based combat style.\nYou will now enter a number for the class you want.\n(1)Scout: Increased hit chance for all attacks.\n(2)Brute: Increased damage for all attacks\n(3)Medic:Increased health during combat.");
   playerClass = in.nextInt();

   switch (playerClass)
   {
       case 1: 
       System.out.println ("You have selected to be a scout! Hit chance increased!");
       break;

       case 2:
       System.out.println ("You have selected to be a brute! Power increased!");
       powerAttackD=b.nextInt(15)+28;                
       regularAttackD=d.nextInt(8)+18;       
       quickAttackD=f.nextInt (4)+4;
       break;

       case 3:
       System.out.println ("You have selected to be a medic! Health increased!");
       userhealth=115;
       break;           
   }

   System.out.println ("You now find yourself in an deserted town center. Pharmacy to your left (Looks to be completely ravaged), restaurant to your right, town hall is a couple hundred feet ahead of you.\nWhere do you want to go?\nPharmacy:1\nRestaurant:2\nTown Hall:3");  
   playerchoice=in.nextInt();

   switch (playerchoice)
   {
       case 1:
       System.out.println ("Nothing of use seems to be apparent when you walk in the door. There is a dead body slouched against the far wall to your right.\nYou make your way down the 5th and middle aisle. Still nothing of use. You get to the end of the store and hit a glass jar of a shelf.\nStill silence in the store. You walk to the entrance of the store empty-handed, and the presumed dead body grabs a hold of you!");
      //BEGINNING OF COMBAT
      Level1ZombieClass Level1ZombieClassObject = new Level1ZombieClass ();
      Level1ZombieClassObject.ZombieLevel1Class();  

   }
```

}
       }

Then my zombie class:

//Turn-based combat with a user input for what they want to do with their attack.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Level1ZombieClass
{
public void ZombieLevel1Class()
{
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   int userhealth=100;
   int comphealth=100;
   int playerClass;
   int hc;
   int userChoice=1;
   int critdamage;
   int regularAttackD;
   int regularAttackHC;
   int powerAttackD;
   int powerAttackHC;
   int shield;
   int quickAttackHC;
   int quickAttackD;
   int compChoice=1;
   int wincount=0;
   boolean winCondition = true;
   Random a = new Random ();
   Random b = new Random ();
   Random c = new Random ();
   Random d = new Random ();
   Random e = new Random ();
   Random f = new Random ();
   Random g = new Random ();
   Random h = new Random (); 

   do  {
   hc=a.nextInt(99)+1;
   powerAttackD=b.nextInt(15)+25;                
   regularAttackD=d.nextInt(8)+15;       
   quickAttackD=f.nextInt (4)+3;
   shield=g.nextInt(15)+10;

   System.out.println ("What move would you like to use?");                       
   System.out.println ("1:Regular Attack");                                 
   System.out.println ("2:Power Attack: Higher damage at a lower hit chance.");                                
   System.out.println ("3:Quick attacks: 3 weaker attacks at a higher hit chance.");                                
   System.out.println ("4:Shield: 100% chance to work and you do not attack, but the damage you receive is reduced for the next incoming attack.");
   userChoice=in.nextInt();
   if (userChoice==1){        
       if (playerClass==2){
        powerAttackD=b.nextInt(15)+28;                
        regularAttackD=d.nextInt(8)+18;       
        quickAttackD=f.nextInt (4)+4;
       }
        if (compChoice==4){            
        regularAttackD=regularAttackD-shield;
        System.out.println ("Level 1 zombie used a shield! Damage reduced by " + shield + ".");         
       } 

       if (playerClass==1){
       if (hc>=14){
           if(regularAttackD<0){
            regularAttackD=0;
        }
        System.out.println ("Attack successful for " + regularAttackD + " damage.");
        comphealth=comphealth-regularAttackD;
        }else{
        System.out.println ("Attack failed!");}        
    }else{                                           
       if (hc>=18){
           if (regularAttackD<0){ 
           regularAttackD=0;
        }
           System.out.println ("Attack successful for " + regularAttackD + " damage.");
           comphealth=comphealth-regularAttackD;

        }else{
            System.out.println ("Attack failed.");
        }
    }

       if (comphealth <=0) {
            System.out.println ("Level 1 zombie health is critically low! You win!");
            wincount++;
            winCondition = false;
            break;
       }   
    System.out.println ("Level 1 zombie health now at " + comphealth + ".");
   } 

   if (userChoice==2){

       if (compChoice==4){
        powerAttackD=powerAttackD-shield;
        System.out.println ("Level 1 zombie used a shield! Damage reduced by " + shield + ".");
       } 

       if (playerClass==1){
       if (hc>=26){
           if(powerAttackD<0){
            regularAttackD=0;
        }
        System.out.println ("Attack successful for " + powerAttackD + " damage.");
        comphealth=comphealth-powerAttackD;
        }else{
        System.out.println ("Attack failed!");}        
    }else{                                           
       if (hc>=30){
           if (powerAttackD<0){ 
           powerAttackD=0;
        }
           System.out.println ("Attack successful for " + powerAttackD + " damage.");
           comphealth=comphealth-powerAttackD;

        }else{
            System.out.println ("Attack failed.");
        }
    }

       if (comphealth <=0) {
        System.out.println ("Level 1 zombie health is critically low! You win!");
        wincount++;
        winCondition = false;
        break;
       }
    System.out.println ("Level 1 zombie health is now at " + comphealth + ".");
    }

   if (userChoice==3)
   {
        quickAttackD=quickAttackD*3;
        if (compChoice==4){
         quickAttackD=quickAttackD-shield;
         System.out.println ("Level 1 zombie used a shield! Damage reduced by " + shield + ".");
        } 

        if (playerClass==1){
       if (hc>=14){
           if(quickAttackD<0){
            quickAttackD=0;
        }
        System.out.println ("Attack successful for " + quickAttackD + " damage.");
        comphealth=comphealth-quickAttackD;
        }else{
        System.out.println ("Attack failed!");}        
    }else{                                           
       if (hc>=18){
           if (quickAttackD<0){ 
           quickAttackD=0;
        }
           System.out.println ("Attack successful for " + quickAttackD + " damage.");
           comphealth=comphealth-quickAttackD;

        }else{
            System.out.println ("Attack failed.");
        }
    }   

        if (comphealth <=0) {
         System.out.println ("Level 1 zombie health is critically low! You win!");
         wincount++;
         winCondition = false;
         break;
        }

       System.out.println ("Level 1 zombie health is now at " + comphealth + ".");
   }

   //BEGINNING OF COMPUTER'S TURN
   compChoice=h.nextInt(3)+1; //the computer's choice of attack.Placed after user turn to prevent a first turn mess up

   hc=a.nextInt(99)+1;
   powerAttackD=b.nextInt(15)+20;                
   regularAttackD=d.nextInt(8)+10;       
   quickAttackD=f.nextInt(4)+1;
   shield=g.nextInt(15)+6;

   if (userhealth<15)
   {
       compChoice=h.nextInt(2)+1;
   }

   if (compChoice==1){        

        if (userChoice==4){
        regularAttackD=regularAttackD-shield;  
        System.out.println ("You have used a shield! Damage reduced by " + shield + ".");
       } 

       if (hc>=20){
            if (regularAttackD<0){ 
           regularAttackD=0;
        }
            System.out.println ("Level 1 zombie's attack successful for " + regularAttackD + " damage.");
            userhealth=userhealth-regularAttackD;
        }else{
            System.out.println ("Level 1 zombie's attack failed.");
        }

       if (userhealth <=0) {
            System.out.println ("You have died.");
            winCondition = false;
            break;
       }   
    System.out.println ("Your health now at " + userhealth + ".");
   } 

   if (compChoice==2){

       if (userChoice==4){
        powerAttackD=powerAttackD-shield;
        System.out.println ("You have used a shield! Damage reduced by " + shield + ".");
       }            

       if (hc>=40){
        if (powerAttackD<0){ 
           powerAttackD=0;
        }

        System.out.println ("Level 1 zombie's power attack hits successfully for " + powerAttackD + " damage!");
        userhealth=userhealth-powerAttackD;
       }else{
        System.out.println ("Oppenent's attack failed!");
       }

       if (userhealth <=0) {
        System.out.println ("You have died.");
        winCondition = false;
        break;
       }
    System.out.println ("Your health is now at " + userhealth + ".");
    }

   if (compChoice==3)
   {
        quickAttackD=quickAttackD*3;
        if (userChoice==4){
         quickAttackD=quickAttackD-shield;
         System.out.println ("You have used a shield! Damage reduced by " + shield + ".");
        } 

        if (hc>=10){
             if (quickAttackD<0){ 
           quickAttackD=0;
        }
         System.out.println ("Level 1 zombie's quick attacks hit for a total of " + quickAttackD + " damage!"); 
         userhealth=userhealth-quickAttackD;
        }else{
         System.out.println ("Level 1 zombie's attack missed!");    
        }           

        if (userhealth <=0) {
         System.out.println ("You have died.");
         winCondition = false;
         break;
        }

       System.out.println ("Your health is now at " + userhealth + ".");
   }


} while (winCondition); //don't define winCondition, IT IS ALREADY TRUE
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a class you should add to it a constructor that have all the parameters entered by the user and pass these parameters when creating the game instance.

For exemple if you need to pass `playerClass` to Level1ZombieClass add in Level1ZombieClass :

```
public Level1ZombieClass (int playerClass, int userhealth, <type> otherParam ...){
    this.playerClass = playerClass;
    this.userhealth = userhealth;
    this.otherParam = otherParam;
    ...
}
```

And when creating the level instance add the variables you need to pass

```
Level1ZombieClass Level1ZombieClassObject = new Level1ZombieClass (playerClass,userhealth,otherParam,...);
```

You will have to (and should) put these variables outside the methods (function) of your class. Your code should be something like this

```
public class Level1ZombieClass
{
    int playerClass;
    int userhealth;
    <type> otherParam;
    ...

public Level1ZombieClass (int playerClass){
    this.playerClass = playerClass;
    this.userhealth = userhealth;
    this.otherParam = otherParam;
    ...
}

public void ZombieLevel1Class()
{
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   //Variables that are not user-dependent
   int comphealth=100;
   int hc;
   int userChoice=1;
   int critdamage;

   //rest of code
```

Comment: Now that worked and I don't get the error message anymore, however it just seems to be ignoring the playerClass value. I select 3 for a "medic" and I go into combat with the zombie. The health still remains 100, when it should be 115...I'm grateful for your help so far, but if you could just bare with me here.. @Younes

Comment: You have two variables `userhealth` one in ZombieLevel1Class and one in RPG class. When you call `userhealth` in ZombieLevel1Class it uses the variable in its own class (witch it value has not changed). As I said above, you should pass all the variables that are modified in RPG and that you need to have in ZombieLevel1Class via the class construct. I'll edit my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: So now I go into combat and right after I attack the zombie attack (which should happen) but then the program ends itself and it says I died.. after only 1 attack.. @Younes

Comment: This question is off topic, you'll have to debug your code yourself to see why this is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `playerClass` value when the `ZombieLevel1Class()` method is called. For example:

```
public void ZombieLevel1Class(int pClass)
{
    int playerClass = pClass;
    //etc etc
}
```

Then you would call the method in the other class like this:

```
Level1ZombieClassObject.ZombieLevel1Class(playerClass);
```